# Apache Virtualhost keeps pointing to default directory

Tags: 11.10, apache2, virtualhost

I have been trying to set an Apache name based Virtual host(http://test.local) to the directory `/var/www/test`, but it keps on pointing to the default `/var/www` directory.

My test.local configuration file looks like this-
http://paste.ubuntu.com/827328/
My hosts file looks like this-
http://paste.ubuntu.com/827338/
And the ports.conf file looks like this-
http://paste.ubuntu.com/827332/

As per suggestion form IRC chat I disabled the `default` Virtualhost, then something wierd happened. Now `http://test.local`, `http://127.0.0.1` loads contents of `/var/www`. But `http://localhost` shows the contents inside `/var/www/test`.

I'm using likewise-ope to connect to windows domian based network, it has created an entry in hosts file(the first line, also included is the next two lines))-

```
127.0.0.1 asset11.domain.com asset11 localhost
127.0.0.1 artis.local
127.0.0.1 test.local
```

How can I make `http://test.local` to point to `/var/www/test` correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local.test file you put on pastebin looks good, just uncomment the directory part.

The `<Directory ...>` - by the way - **must** point to the same path as the DocumentRoot (`/var/www/test/` in your case).

Then you need to activate that file through `sudo a2ensite test.local` and reload your apache with `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But as far as I know <Directory /> directives are not absolutely necessary, but can be used where we need some directory specific directives.

Comment: I counsel always to use the directory directives, because it happened too often to me that a .htaccess didn't worked. Of course it is not absolutely necessary.